# Videos Play with twice the normal speed, no sound

Tags: sound, multimedia

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo Ideapad 500 laptop, and I have the problem that all my multimedia files( YouTube, VLC , RhythmBox) are playing at twice the normal speed, with no sound. What steps can I take?

Comment: Does this issue happen with flash video running over firefox also ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a common problem people encounter from time to time (Possibly due to the driver/device being used but also seems to be related to pulseaudio).

Apparently, people have suggested that the following should resolve it:

- Completely restart the machine.
- Go to the sound options (System > Preferences > Sound) and play with the options and see what results you get.

There is a nice discussion about this in the Ubuntu forums [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1679220)

Comment: Actually, I have tried almost everything mentioned in the link given, and it isnt working yet. Seems to be a driver problem as my friend, who bought the same laptop, is facing the exact same problem. Videos aren't working anywhere, not even firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04: The solution that worked for me was to disable "RV710/730 HDMI Audio (Radeon HD4000 series. Digital Stereo (HDMI)" that I found under System>Preferences>Hardware>Sound>Output. What I found concerning was why this suddenly happened without my intervention.